# how to sort an array of dictionaries depending on several properties of the dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I need to sort an array of dictionaries (as close to quick sort as possible), using a keyed object from the dictionary, However because of the complexity of my dictionary (number of keyed valued) and data that can be returned in them I need to be able to sort each dictionary based off several of the keyed values in the dictionary.

for instance, say if dictionay keyvalue1 in array[0], array[1] are equal, then check if keyvalue2 is equal, if yes then continue down the list of keyvalues till the two items that you can sort array[0] & [1] on.

I have read about NSSortDescriptor and specifying the property to compare with where you can set ascending or descending, but I am not sure if this could be used to achive what I am wanting to achieve.

I have been given an example of what I need to do but its in delphi, which I am not very familiar with, however I think the example gives some insight as to what I am trying to do.

```
//
Result := AnsiCompareText (left.property1, right.Property1);
if Result <> 0 then Exit;
Result := AnsiCompareText (left.property2, right.Property2);
if Result <> 0 then Exit;
Result := AnsiCompareText (left.property3, right.Property3);
if Result <> 0 then Exit;
Result := AnsiCompareText (left.property4, right.Property4);
if Result <> 0 then Exit;
Result := AnsiCompareText (left.property5, right.Property5);
if Result <> 0 then Exit;
//
```

Hopefully this will give you some idea as to what I am trying to achieve, any help would be greatly appreciated been stuck on this for a while now, if you know of a similar solution in objective C i would love to hear it! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you have a mutable array. Then you use this:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)
{
  // you have two items - use whatever complex logic you want, then return
  // one of NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending
} ];
```

For instance, suppose all you cared about was a "name" property:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)
{
  NSString *n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"name"];
  NSString *n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"name"];
  return [n1 localizedCompare:n2];
} ];
```

There really nice thing about this technique is that the logic can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: just a question about your code, would I need to put this into some type of loop or dose sortUsingComparator cycle through the array(soon to be mutable array) and place each dictionary object into d1 then d2, so on and so forth like qucksort? or is this just for an array with 2 dictionary objects in it?

Comment: ah right, I just saw a similar example to your second section of code after searching NSComparisonResult :) My one last question would be what if name from d1 and d2 are identical and then I would like to stort using lastname.. what would the logic look like.. I am not sure how the return would work or how how to structure.. this.. I hope this makes sense

Comment: So if both names are equal, that is the comparison is "NSOrderedSame", then you do another comparison, and you either return ascending or descending, or if they are equal you do another comparison. You can get pretty deeply indented doing this, so you would just do the return first if not the same, then you can continue on at the same indent level. What is in the block is just plain ole normal code.